# Find file, delete when same file name is found with different extension

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to first FIND anything that has .log extension. For the files that are found, if the same filename exists with .txt extension, REMOVE file with .txt extension.

I'm guessing I need to use the `BaseName`, but not sure how to go about that.

If the following files exists: test1.log, test2.log, test1.txt

Remove test1.txt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
Get-ChildItem *.log -Recurse | Where-Object {
  -not $_.PSIsContainer
} | ForEach-Object {
  $txtfile = Join-Path $_.Directory ($_.BaseName + '.txt')
  if (Test-Path -LiteralPath $txtfile) {
    Remove-Item $txtfile -Force
  }
}
```

Comment: Awesome. Quick Response! so if I want to look in C:\ directory, is it: Get-ChildItem *.log -Recurse | C:\

Comment: No. It's `Get-ChildItem C:\*.log -Recurse | ...`.

Comment: It Worked!! THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way using the Compare-Object:

```
$ref = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log | Select BaseName -ExpandProperty Basename
$dif = Get-ChildItem -Filter *.log | Select BaseName -ExpandProperty Basename

Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $ref -DifferenceObject $dif -IncludeEqual -ExcludeDifferent | % {
  Remove-Item "$($_.InputObject).txt"
}
```